# Submitting a Value via Hyperlink without Page Reload Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to make my chat pop up without reloading and I'm using hyperlink to pass the user_id

This is how I did it before (with page load)

Link format:

```
<a  target='_top' 'style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;margin-left:20;' href='index.php?to=USER001'><b>";
```

this will redirect me back to my index with $_GET['to'] = USER001 (but the page reloads)

I remade it so that the page doesn't reload
*new link format*

```
<a  target='_top' 'style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;margin-left:20;' href='#' rel ='index.php?to="USER001"'><b>";
```

it sends me to localhost/index.php#
I notice that if i do it this way it will not give me the value so i made it into

```
<a  target='_top' 'style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;margin-left:20;' href='#USER001' rel ='index.php?to="USER001"'><b>";
```

can I get the value USER001 with this if so how? Is there a better way to do this?

I am trying to get the value USER001

Comment: 1st of all, get rid of quotes in url, `index.php?to=USER001` is good enough

Comment: Sorry bout that the original code actually is connected to a database and I just use a static/fixed value for easy representation

Comment: where do you want to get it? on client or sever side? what for?

Comment: I need it to be on the client, I need the ID so that my chatbox can distinguish which user I am chatting with, so I will get the value and then run it on a query (that is already made and working(tested with the page reload))

Comment: maybe you should search about how to work with url in javascript

Comment: My main problem is that when I click the hyperlink everything happens but is the setting are being overwritten when the page settles -.-

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the # character to disable the hyperlink
you should write

```
<a  target='_top' 'style='text-decoration:none;color:#fff;margin-left:20;' href='javascript:;' rel ='index.php?to="USER001"'>
```

but mind that you need to define the click action in javascript, jquery or what ever you are using.

if you write in jQuery

```
$(a).click(function(){alert(0);});
```

the the click will alert 0 but will not redirect you to '/' folder.
the cancellation of href should be href="javascript:;" and not href="#" as written in a lot of places in the web

Comment: what exactly do you need to do? open a new window with the param ?to=SOME_USER_ID?

Comment: Nope get the value SOME_USER_ID and pass it to the same page without reloading via hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

1. add an id attribute to the hyperlink (lets say `test_a`)
2. add attribute `data-user-id="USER_001"` to the hyper link
3. in your javascript write:

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var user_id = $("#test_a").attr('data-user-id'); // will get you the value you need
   });
   ```

Once you have it in the javascript you can pass it to the server with ajax or you can use it in the current page without refreshing

Comment: There is more than one user isn't it bad to have the same id attribute value?

Comment: yes it is, you shouldn't have more then one id. ok forget the id, just use $(this).attr('data-user-id'); and the line will retrieve the user id from the data-user-id attribute from the specific heperlink you just pressed